# Problem deleting numbers when adding commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a comma to the value entered by the user using the following code

```js
$("#youpay").on('keyup', function() {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control english text-center" id="youpay" type="number">
```

But the problem is that when the input length reaches 4, the input value is cleared.
I used this code in another part and it was not a problem, but I do not know what the problem is here

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't try to reinvent the wheel and use one of the many formatting utilities out there, like [AutoNumeric](http://autonumeric.org/)? THey have it all sorted for you

Comment: `type="number"` is to blame here: there's only a limited set of characters that it can accept, and it seems that `,` is not supported in your locale. Do you really need it?

Comment: Yes I need to use it. Is there a solution? Other than using side libraries @raina77ow

Comment: Then you need to reconsider using `,` as separator, as type=number input doesn't support it. Formatting libraries won't help actually; the best they can do is have some overlay on top of input essentially duplicating the input. That's clunky and tends to have weird bugs.

Comment: I can’t verify this at the moment, but it’s *possible* that `<input type=“text” inputmode=“numeric”>` might allow you to work around this, as it gives handheld users the numeric keyboard, but still allows a range of text input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the code so that new value (that is about to be put into an input) is logged immediately after replacement, for example:

```js
$("#youpay").on('keyup', function() {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    const newValue = value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    console.log(`${value} is replaced by ${newValue}`);
    return newValue;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control english text-center" id="youpay" type="number">
```

... you'll see that the replacement actually works correctly: `1111` is replaced by `1,111`, etc. The real reason here is not JS, but HTML.

See, applying `type="number"` to input is supposed to simplify user input validation, but doesn't play well with decorations adding non-numeric characters to it. [Quoting the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number#using_number_inputs):

> Important: Bear in mind that, logically, you should not be able to
> enter characters inside a number input other than numbers. There seems
> to be some disagreement about this among browsers; see bug 1398528.

In particular, any attempt to supply non-purely-numeric string to `<input type="number">` as its value causes the whole value to be discarded. That's why you see empty string after entering 4th number.